# Background image for Accordion panel

Tags: primefaces

I'm on PrimeFaces 6.2 with JoinFaces on SpringBoot. I have a page with a single Accordion panel as the sole component. What I'm trying to achieve is not exactly a background image "for" the Accordion, but rather this:

- I want to display a logo positioned at the bottom-center of the page
- the logo always remains bottom-centered, no matter how the user maximizes/changes resolution of the browser.
- when I expand the panels of the Accordion, it would overlap and conceal the logo in the background.
- when I collapse the panels, the Accordion shrinks and the logo in the background becomes visible again.

Till now, I have neither been able to position an image at the bottom center of the screen...nor, how to do such an overlapping of the Accordion over the logo. Can somebody please advise how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I badly misunderstood my problem. This has nothing to do with tweaking the Accordion. It's just about having a full page background image in HTML.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp